# What does Spark do if a node running a .foreach() fails?

Tags: apache-spark

We have a large RDD with millions of rows. Each row needs to be processed with a third-party optimizer that is licensed (Gurobi). We have a limited number of licenses.

We have been calling the optimizer in the Spark `.map()` function. The problem is that Spark will run many more mappers than it needs and throw away the results. This causes a problem with license exhaustion.

We're looking at calling Gurobi inside the Spark `.foreach()` method. This works, but we have two problems:

1. Getting the data back from the optimizer into another RDD.  Our tentative plan for this is to write the results into a database (e.g. MongoDB or DynamoDB).
2. What happens if the node on which the `.foreach()` method dies? Spark guarantees that each foreach only runs once. Does it detect that it dies and restart it elsewhere? Or does something else happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if task executed with `foreachPartition` dies a whole job dies.

This means that, if not additional steps are taken to ensure correctness, partial result might have been acknowledged by an external system, leading to inconsistent state.

Considering limited number of licenses `map` or `foreachPartition` shouldn't make any difference. Not going into discussion if using Spark in this case makes any sense, the best way to resolve it, is to limit number of executor cores, to the number of licenses you own.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me at a good reference that discusses # of executors, # of executor cores, and the total # of cores?

Answer (score 0):

If the goal here is to limit just X number of concurrent calls, I would repartition the RDD with x, and then run a partition level operation. I think that should keep you from exhausting the licenses.

Comment: That's what we've been doing (although, more correctly, we have limited the number of executors). However, unknown to use, the same RDD is being executed simultaneously on different executors. ...  It seems that there are several issues. One, perhaps, is that the license manager just can't handle all of the simultaneous connections!

Comment: That doesn’t sound the same. Each executor can have multiple partitions. If your license can handle just 2 then try 1 executor with 2 partitions.

Comment: Okay... How do I specify the number of partitions per executor?